# Efficient parser to convert XML to JSON in java without JsonObject and Array

Tags: java, json, xml, stax

I tried to convert XML to JSON in java. I am using Stax parser for Conversion. After getting START_ELEMENT, END_ELEMENT, CHARACTERS, I don't know how to convert it to JSON Format. Not use any inbuilt libraries, JsonObject, JSonArray.IS any logic available For this conversion...

Comment: what are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code to convert XML to JSON. Create a java project in eclipse since I am creating a java project I will manually import the Java-json.jar by right-clicking on the project and select configure build path their by selecting the add external jar option add the jar file and run the project. If you are building using maven project add the following dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20140107</version>
```

```
package com.test.jsontoxml
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class JsonConversion {

 public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to JSON</test>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware of doing evil with this code!  https://www.json.org/license.html

Answer (score 3):

Why not use already existing JARs to do the job.
One such efficient parser is present in java-json
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Conversion can be done in one line using

```
import org.json.XML;

....

JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject("Your XML Here");
```

Comment: Java-json, Google's gson, faster-xml json etc are used very very widely from small to extremely large projects. When trustworthy people develop thoroughly tested and efficient parsers, I find it surprising that you want your own parser.

Comment: The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.  https://www.json.org/license.html

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert xml to json. I am the maintainer of the project. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Dzd)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class JsonConversion {
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to JSON</test>";
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = U.xmlToJson(TEST_XML_STRING);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        // {
        //   "test": {
        //     "-attrib": "moretest",
        //     "#text": "Turn this to JSON"
        //   }
        // }
    }
}
```